# Compiler error when I run ng serve in angular2

Tags: angular

ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader!./src/styles.css

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.css'

```
in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\A NG2\mobufinancialment\src'
@ ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader!./src/styles.css 3:10-201 
@ ./src/styles.css
@ multi ./src/styles.css
```

Comment: What steps are necessary to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have something like this in your styles.css file:

```
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

You need to change it to this:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

Explanation is here: https://github.com/angular/material2/releases

Answer (score 0):

With given information, It will be best to move your Angular2-material theming to index.html like

```
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/@angular/material@2.0.0-beta.3/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Just using this in main index.html is enough for this one file. Check this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2N3t8kuduOXoxSlDvLcZ?p=preview)